dynamically mapping an excel spreadsheet using python and pandas
I have a large excel spreadsheet that I need to read data from certain rows, columns and cells and then output into a different dataframe format. How would I capture the data in specific cells while also ensuring the data can be captured when the spreadsheet is changed? Meaning more columns or rows could be added, but I need to continuously capture this data. Could you provide the code using python and pandas and using loops to dynamically capture this data. Again, not all cells will be used and only certain rows and columns will be used. Here is an example.
Logic
Display the count of the column name for a given quarter and ID. In this case: q1.22. I created new columns called: date and TYPE
Here is the excel spreadsheet:
Data
        q1.22           
ID      type1   OFFICE  nontype1    Customer
NY      1       3       1           2
CA      1       33      1           0
TOTALS  2       36      2           1


data = {
    '0': ['id', 'NY', 'CA', 'TOTALS'],
    'q1.22': ['type1', '1', '1', '2'],
    '0_2': ['OFFICE', '3', '33', '36'],
    '0_3': ['nontype1', '1', '1', '2'],
    '0_4': ['Customer', '2', '0', '1']
}

Desired
ID  date    TYPE
NY  q1.22   type1
NY  q1.22   nontype1
NY  q1.22   Customer
NY  q1.22   Customer
CA  q1.22   type1
CA  q1.22   nontype1

Doing
# Define the row indices for both ranges
start_row, end_row = 0, 3  # Rows 1 to 4 (0-based index)

# Define the column indices for the first range (A to C)
start_col_range1, end_col_range1 = 0, 2  # Columns A to C (0-based index)

# Define the column indices for the second range (E to F)
start_col_range2, end_col_range2 = 4, 5  # Columns E to F (0-based index)

# Create an empty list to store the captured data
captured_data = []

# Loop through rows and columns within the first range (A to C)
for row in range(start_row, end_row + 1):
    row_label = df.iloc[row, 0]  # Assuming the ID column is in the first column
    for col in range(start_col_range1, end_col_range1 + 1):
        col_label = df.columns[col]
        value = df.iloc[row, col]
        captured_data.append({'ID': row_label, 'date': df.iloc[0, 0], 'TYPE': col_label})

# Loop through rows and columns within the second range (E to F)
for row in range(start_row, end_row + 1):
    row_label = df.iloc[row, 0]  # Assuming the ID column is in the first column
    for col in range(start_col_range2, end_col_range2 + 1):
        col_label = df.columns[col]
        value = df.iloc[row, col]
        captured_data.append({'ID': row_label, 'date': df.iloc[0, 0], 'TYPE': col_label})

# Convert the captured data into a DataFrame
output_df = pd.DataFrame(captured_data)

However, this is the output:
ID  date    TYPE
0   id  id  Unnamed: 0
1   id  id  q1.22
2   NY  id  Unnamed: 0
3   NY  id  q1.22
4   CA  id  Unnamed: 0
5   CA  id  q1.22
6   TOTALS  id  Unnamed: 0
7   TOTALS  id  q1.22
8   id  id  Unnamed: 3
9   id  id  Unnamed: 4
10  NY  id  Unnamed: 3
11  NY  id  Unnamed: 4
12  CA  id  Unnamed: 3
13  CA  id  Unnamed: 4
14  TOTALS  id  Unnamed: 3
15  TOTALS  id  Unnamed: 4

Any suggestion is appreciated

explain logic of desired output.

yes I just updated

provide the code for us to generate input dataframe.

ok I updated thank you

You should load your data as a MultiIndex, not with type/office/... as a row. Then this would be a simple stack.

Ok this is how the spreadsheet is set up though. This is the dilemma… unless you mean for me to convert first to where the columns are row data? @mozway - I just wish to read and extract data from certain rows and columns in this large spreadsheet dynamically

The question is unclear, is this about how to load this particular dataset? Or how to generalize the import (in which case we have no information about what you're currently doing)? Please provide a way to reproduce the excel file (you are currently only providing a python dictionary) and the code to load your data.

No it’s just about capturing certain cells from the provided dataset and create a new dataframe with a different format @mozway

Then we're missing information to understand/reproduce your issue. Providing a dictionary of whatever you have after your own import is not helpful since the issue is how to import the data correctly in the first place.

Ok I’m not understanding what I need to show. The data provided is an example of the spreadsheet (dataframe) I’ll continue to research thanks

To be clear, it is possible to convert a dataframe as given in your current example into your desired output, but this would not be elegant. Importing the data correctly as a MultiIndex in the first place (one level for the quarter, a second level for the type/office/no type/customer) is the correct way to go.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Ok I’ll research this thanks @mozway

I added links to duplicates on how to correctly load an excel sheet with a MultiIndex. In short you must have something like header=[0,1] in you read_excel parameters. Then you will be able to stack or melt the data easily. If you have issues, please edit the question and provide the exact read_excel code that you are currently using.

Ok I don’t think you should have closed the question because I am wanting specific rows/columns. I then want to be able to capture data when rows and or columns are added @mozway. It’s not just reading headers, but has to only take in rows up to a certain point

@Lynn then, as already mentioned above, the question would lack too many details to be reproducible. The question is fundamentally about how to load data from excel and you don't show at all the excel file, instead you show a dictionary of what you have after your own import (you also failed to show how you currently import the data, please provide this code). I've quite sure you just need to use the correct header parameter as shown in the duplicates.
